# Mongoose: aggregate query to return an array of strings instead to array of objects

Tags: mongoose, aggregation-framework

I want to make the same operation like this to return an array of strings:

```
model.find().distinct("some_field")
```

How it's possible to take the same result using aggregation function?

Answer (score 2):

You can use below code to get all unique `some_field` using aggregate:

```js
model.aggregate([
    {
        $group:{
           _id: null,
           some_field: { $addToSet: '$some_field' }
        }
    }
]);
```